# Automatic integration between different VCS

Tags: svn, merge, continuous-integration, perforce

I have a task to implement continuous automated merging from a big, open source, svn-based project to forked perforce repository (our customer requires perforce). Customer features/changes are developed in perforce and we need continuously integrate new changes from upstream svn repository to perforce.

I clearly understand, that I can't get a perfect tool which will do all work for me, because collisions between community and our changes obviously will happen and they should be solved by human, but my target is to make this process as much as possible automated. Integrator should pay attention only when something definitely went wrong. To drive automated tasks I'm using Hudson, but I think this isn't important. I'm just searching for a tool which can do following things for me:

- tool should take svn changeset
- apply diffs to perforce fork
- delete/rename/move files in perforce accordingly to svn (if any)
- commit changes to perforce
- return error if some step can't be completed

Which tool could help me to do such automated merges between different VCS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### General Method

This method works for nearly any situation, including getting a library as a straight tarball with no source control information.

When doing something like this, I always find it helpful to keep the clean, original source in one place in perforce (//depot/thirdparty/library, or something similar).  This should always be the unaltered code from the version of the external library that you are using.  After this is in Perforce, integrate from it to your version, and only make the changes you require (if any) to this new version.

When the original library changes and you want to update, go into the thirdparty source, forcibly overwrite everything with the new source, and then tell perforce that what is on disk is the correct version (I forget the commands, but the question has been answered here on StackOverflow), and submit that.  Note that if you want to actually track file renames, this won't work, but for general code development it does well.

At this point, you have an updated library, which you can then integrate into your working tree again.  This will use Perforce to track the diffs you applied, if any, against the changes in the source library.  Perforce is generally pretty good about detecting conflicting changes, so this should reduce the number of places that need to be inspected by hand.

Once this is in place, you can automate a number of the steps, and when Perforce doesn't detect any conflicts, the whole update may be done automatically.

This does tend to work better for libraries with occasional updates, but there is no reason why it couldn't work with a frequently updating source.

### Tool Integration

Recent versions of Perforce include a git-compatible mode, and git itself can pull from an svn repository, so you should be able to use git as an intermediary to handle updates with more detail in the changes.  Here as well, there should be some place that is considered canonical source, one place that contains the changes made to the library, and the resulting code that Perforce uses.  If your client desires Perforce, I'd recommend that Perforce be used to track the alterations to the original library, but theoretically the git bridge could be used for this as well.

Comment: Seems you mean reconcile feature. Same approach we are using now, but open source project is huge - it has about 10k files. File/folder renamings/movements isn't rare operation there. Using reconcile approach we can lose our local changes when upstream file was moved/renamed: in such case file will be treated as deleted in one place and new file appeared in another. This obviously will lead to lose of our changes in "deleted" file. We definitely need to avoid such cases. Perforce merging system is quite smart, but problem is in tracking such kind of changes in "foreign" vcs.

Comment: Regarding git - I need to check this, since we still using p4 clients version 2012 and 2010 as server (this is our customer environment), so there also could be some restrictions with git on such old p4 versions, but thanks for advice - I definitely give a try to this approach.

Comment: @stunpix: Reconcile was indeed the word I couldn't remember.  I could be mistaken, since I haven't tried it recently, but if you make your changes in a different branch from that being reconciled in Perforce, it should at least warn you about a file being deleted that you had changed.  It isn't as automated as you would like, I'm sure, but at least you'll be notified rather than just losing it quietly.